# https request on winRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I need to send this request :

```
POST /params/initProvisioning HTTP/1.1
Host: serverIp:4443
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{
    "mobileOS":"WindowsPhone",
    "pushId":"https://db3.notify.windows.com/?token=AwYAAAA...",
    "deviceType":"type"
}
```

When I use PostMan tool to send it, everything works fine. But when I send it from my windows phone 8.1 app I receive an error 404 not found :

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("{");
foreach (Parameter p in parameters)
    sb.Append(ParameterToJsonString(p));
sb.Append("}");
Debug.WriteLine("params to send : {0}", sb.ToString());

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri("https://serverIp:4443/params/initProvisioning"),
    new StringContent(sb.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

Is there a special client for https protocol ?

Comment: I'd recommend inspecting both requests (Postman and Mobile Client) in Fiddler.  That should highlight any difference between how the two requests are constructed and give you some insight as to how you should change your code.

Comment: The app uses a SDK that can be compile only on ARM processor, so I need to test it from a real device, not the emulator.

Comment: I would say that it is some header missing from your WP request. You can connect your real device to Fiddler using a proxy. Then compare the requests.
http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/UseFiddlerAsReverseProxy